# Why does my code work in pycharm but not in visual studio code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, pygame, png

My main problem is on the import of images in python.

Here is the code that concerns it:

```
import pygame
import neat
import time
import os
import random
pygame.font.init()

WIN_WIDTH = 500
WIN_HEIGHT = 800


BIRD_IMGS = [pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "bird1.png"))), pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "bird2.png"))), pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "bird3.png")))]
PIPE_IMG = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "pipe.png")))
BASE_IMG = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "base.png")))
BG_IMG = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "bg.png")))
```

the error message is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Dell\Documents\Code Projects\Python\Machine learning\Floppy Bord\flappy_bird_noai.py", line 12, in <module>
    BIRD_IMGS = [pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "bird1.png"))), pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "bird2.png"))), pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "bird3.png")))]
pygame.error: Couldn't open imgs\bird1.png
```

However in pycharm all works fine. Ive already tried changing the python interpreter. Both use the anaconda base. Thank you for the time reading this!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the file bird3.png is not available from the VS code project, make sure that the file is in the proper location.

Answer (score 0):

I know from my own personal experience this is due to the PYTHONPATH file not being set correctly in your venv.

Try using the following command in your vs code

export PYTHONPATH=.

That might fix the issue you are having.

Comment: I found the solution to the problem it was actually the directory in my terminal that didnt match with what was in the code. Thanks for your time